# setting background image for html coding not effected in android

Tags: android, html, webview

i want to display the html data in webview in android like the following.

[image]

i placed my background images in drawable-hdpi folder, and i gave path as below.But it is not effected.

```
String strBody="<html><body>";
     for (int i = 0; i < dslist.size(); i++) { 
      if(dslist.get(i).getFrom().equals("inbox"))
        {
         strBody += "<div style='word-break:break-all;background-image:url('../res/drawable-hdpi/msgblue_box.png');width:60%; ;padding:20px;margin:2%'>" +   dslist.get(i).getBody()+"</br>"+dslist.get(i).getDateformat()+ "</div>";
            }
       else
        {     
     strBody += "<div style='background-image:url('../res/drawable-hdpi/msgblue_box.png');width:60%;margin:2%;margin-left:30%;padding:20px;'>" +dslist.get(i).getBody()+"</br>"+dslist.get(i).getDateformat()+ "</div>";
        }

          }
      strBody+= "<br /> <br /></body></html>";

      webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, strBody, null, "utf-8", null);][1]
```

Comment: Check whether the path of image is correct / check whether if condition is satisfied..

Comment: try by putting images in assets folder.

Comment: I tried both ways what you suggested @Beginner , Ali Imran

Comment: try to run in some browser like chrome, mozilla... and check for the error in browser console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this images in "assets folder" and try this way

```
String strBody="<html><body>";
     for (int i = 0; i < dslist.size(); i++) { 
      if(dslist.get(i).getFrom().equals("inbox"))
        {
         strBody += "<div style='word-break:break-all;background-image:url(file:///android_asset/msgblue_box.png);width:60%; ;padding:20px;margin:2%'>" +   dslist.get(i).getBody()+"</br>"+dslist.get(i).getDateformat()+ "</div>";
            }
       else
        {     
     strBody += "<div style='background-image:url(file:///android_asset/msgblue_box.png);width:60%;margin:2%;margin-left:30%;padding:20px;'>" +dslist.get(i).getBody()+"</br>"+dslist.get(i).getDateformat()+ "</div>";
        }

          }
      strBody+= "<br /> <br /></body></html>";

      webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, strBody, null, "utf-8", null);][1]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it is also not effected. @Biraj

Comment: its working for me after removing     '       ' , for file:///android_asset/msgblue_box.png.

Comment: I edit the post. Please accept so other can trust and use the solution